# Raspberry pi 3 and .net 5 coreclr

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, coreclr

My aim is to install .net 5 coreclr on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows core IoT. I know this is possible with v2 but do you know if this scenario is covered for now with the new version ? I know that it seem odd that v3 can’t do it but I tried to deploy a console with 2 different versions of coreclr for ARM and result is not satisfying (no error message in power shell console… website don’t launch)

Comment: You might have better luck on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Set `DNX_TRACE=1` to see more traces and update the question with the result. I think the issue might be related to the CPU - Raspberry PI2 was ARM if Raspberry Pi 3 is ARM64 then AFAIK there is no CoreClr for ARM64 at this point.

Comment: I see that the insider build 10.0.14262.1000 for Raspberry PI 3 is ARMx86...

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers !
@Pawer, when I try to add SET DNX_TRACE=1 to cmd, I get absolutly no output at all. I try echo = on to get excecution path and it appear that instruction is read...
Have you any idea about release date on ARMx64 ?

Comment: you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560892/is-net-core-ready-to-run-on-raspberry-pi-3/39589302#39589302 ?