# Is .NET Core ready to run on Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: .net, raspbian, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I can find a lot of obsolete threads but a lot have been changed the last months.

Is there currently any possibility to run .NET Core and/or ASP.NET Core on Raspberry with Raspbian (currently Jessie) *without* Mono? Or what do I need?

I can find some dnvm samples, but I cannot find one tutorial which is up to date and uses the dotnet cli. I know Windows 10 IoT is planned for v1.1.0 but I can find nothing for ARM based CPUs. Also there is no Docker sample for ASP.NET Core on Raspbian...

Even http://dot.net shows only a Homebrew install command but how to install .NET Core 1.0.1 on Raspbian / Linux without Homebrew.

Comment: Samsung has been working with Microsoft on the ARM port, but I don't think that has finished.

Comment: You can follow the progress here https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3977

Answer (score 24, accepted):

.NET Core is scheduled to run on ARM based OS like Raspian / Windows 10 IoT for Q4 2016 / Q1 2017.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/

At this point of time I think you can follow the installations for Debian but you should get a `exec format error` IIRC.

Edit 3/10/17: first official instruction is online now: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

Comment: I took a look at the link, but does that mean that ASP.NET Core will come also to ARM soon? Because it has its own section in that link.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I would say yes. .NET Core now runs on ARM https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

Comment: I didn't know that, do you mean using `mono`? or can it be used natively on `linux` box without `mono`? Could you provide me with some links how to do that?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Mono has nothing todo with .NET Core. Mono was the base of DNX but was removed with .NET Core. There is no dependency  in this case now.

Comment: I am now trying this link, hope this work http://dotnetcorechris.github.io/dotnetcoreonraspberrypi.html

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin did u not read my link https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md ? This is the current state and works like a charm.

Comment: Actually that works just for the simple consol apps, but did you try it with a asp.net web application? that didn't work for me, I cannot start the application, if you managed to run Asp.net app could you tell how please? this is a part of the error I get `Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: You've asked "will that come for ASP.NET Core come soon?" I said yes. But unfortunately at this time it is not supported and I do not know anybody who could set up ASP.NET Core on ARM at this time.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md first official instruction

Comment: https://www.leowkahman.com/2017/07/16/running-dotnet-core-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/ ... I have put together a simple tutorial on how to get it running on Raspbian

Answer (score 3):

Now you CAN run dotnet core applications on Raspberry PI 3, with no Mono installed at all.

I managed to run complex app on headless Ubuntu Server 16.04 and on Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

All you have to do is to get the build output of cross compilation of coreclr and corefx, remove private and pre-compiled dlls, and put your managed dlls on the PI along with them.

Then you can run it using "corerun" executable.

(I posted a video on that one but it seems to be illegal to post it here)

Anyhow, to answer your question : it is now possible to run dotnet core apps on RPI3, although it isn't released yet.

Comment: Can you give me any keywords on how to find the video? I am really interested in this but all I find is either obsolete or for Windows IoT.

Comment: try finding this at youtube : Setting up RavenDB on the Raspberry PI (hibernatingrhinos, ravendb, raspberry pi).   At any case we already managed to run dotnet core on Raspbian too (raspbian is much more stable then the unofficial ubuntu server for rpi3, imho)

Comment: @NicolasR here is a link on how to run .net core on raspberry pi: https://dotnetcorechris.github.io/dotnetcoreonraspberrypi.html

Comment: @DamianGalletini Your comment should be the current answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a (seemingly) stable build of .Net Core on Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 by following Peter Marcu's instructions here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

You don't need to use "corerun", you can use "dotnet". You build on your dev machine and copy to your Pi.

Update: I realise now the original question specifically mentioned Rasbian (Jessie). The method at that link requires Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04. But if that isn't a problem I think you should be good to go.

Comment: See my comment to @emseetea here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907857/is-it-possible-to-run-net-core-on-raspberry-pi - you can run dotnet core on Raspbian/Jessie.  Basically, cross-compiling coreclr+fx, together with apt-get installing gcc-5 and libicu57 (from "scratch" source) made it happen on the Rasbian OS.   It might work (I didn't try) with the  https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md binaries together with gcc-5 and libicu57 too.   And may I add : Rasbian "feels" more stable with dotnet core on the Pi then with Ubuntu (no offense)

Answer (score 0):

Officially for the 1.0 release, [no](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/140#issuecomment-229861752). The only runtimes available for ARM is currently the [Windows ones](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json).

Also, Homebrew is for OSX. What you want to be looking at in the future for on Raspbian is the [Debian instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#debian).

Comment: Thank you I'll check that. At this point of time, .NET Core is not very neat documentated.. :-(